# Display the packages installed in a docker image without running the image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to find the packages installed in a centos or ubuntu based docker image without running the docker image

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, however, if you have access to the image Dockerfile you can have a look at what packages are being installed otherwise, running the command below will display the layers of an image:

```
docker image history --no-trunc image_name > image_history
```

Answer (score 0):

Posted a similar question and got a very good answer:

[Docker image - universal way to list packages installed in an image without running it by analyzing the binary only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430168/docker-image-universal-way-to-list-packages-installed-in-an-image-without-runn)

For Ubuntu, I think `dpkg-query` is available. Check doc: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-query.1.html

Somehow I got a format more or less working, but `${Version}` sometimes has a `1` or `2` suffixed in the beginning, don't sure what it means.

```
dpkg-query -W -f '${Package}:${Version}:${Architecture}\n'
```