# Red Hat base image - list packages installed in an image with "rpm", without running it

Tags: docker

Our org builds apps based on some Red Hat base images, we find that `rpm -qa` can be used to check installed system packages and run security checks. Here "packages" means system libs, like `libxml2` or `expat`.(For software dependencies we have Maven). From the dockerfiles, we know that it's not downloading sources and install from it, so in theory, all packages are detected by `rpm`.

Some of them always pointing to `latest`, I have to check regularly to make sure which package is at which level. Need to automate this.

When it's impossible to run the image first(for example, when entrypoint is defined as `java -jar`), I cannot easily run the container and run `rpm -qa`. I have to create a project, create a main class doing some long-running job, set all the things in Maven jib plugin, build and run it, and `docker exec xxx rpm -qa`. It's inconvenient.

I have tried `dive`, I see things but I cannot view the content. I can `docker save -o foo.tar` and try to extract files from there, but it's inconvenient. Besides, I am not aware of any file containing a list of packages installed. Is there any?

Tried `docker history`, not very helpful.

I would like a feature from `docker` to list all packages and versions, for vulnerability checks, delegating the listing of packages to `rpm` or `dpkg`(for Ubuntu based images, maybe in the future) depending on the availability of any one of them.

`dockerfile` can be inaccessible if the image comes from some remote registry. Needs to analyze the binary.

Comment: There are so many ways to create Docker images that I don't think this is a solvable problem.  Consider not just the different package managers you list, but also packages installed from source vs. via the package manager, or compiled languages where the libraries might still have vulnerabilities but not be directly visible in the image, or....

Comment: Yes, but for the base image I am using now, `rpm` somehow gets all packages. If installed from source(in the dockerfile), does `rpm` takes it into account when the image is there? If yes, then it's good enough for me. For applications dependencies I have Maven; I just need to know system packages.

Comment: If it was installed from source (maybe `make && make install`) then `rpm` won't know about it.

Comment: OK so good to know. Then it's another thing. I would change the question to more specific, like how to check Red Hat base image installed packages(checking the dockerfile, I know it's not installing from source)

Comment: Have you seen Snyk?

Comment: No. Seems Snyk does this job for us at first glance. OK a good suggestion, I will talk with CI and managers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the default `ENTRYPOINT` of a given image is on your way for a particular operation, you can unilaterally decide to change it to whatever you want at run time, even to totally drop it.

In your particular case, this should do the trick:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint '' <your_image> rpm -it
```

Change the final command to the one you need. You can even run bash and interactively enter your own set of commands to inspect.

Comment: OK that is very good knowledge to know. Actually the command is `rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}:%{VERSION}:%{RELEASE}:%{ARCH}\\n"` but what you said works, great! Thanks.

Comment: For images based on Ubuntu/Centos, I use dpkg-query: dpkg-query -W -f '${Package}:${Version}:${Architecture}\n' somehow works; but %{Version} sometimes has 1 or 2 prefixed, not sure what it means.

Answer (score 0):

use `syft image:tag` to list all package in images

Comment: what is syft? Not found anywhere in path. And it sounds like an alias?